# What does "young pup covering" mean?

Tags: spoken-english

Watching [**this video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B0cBnhuLy-Y&t=29s), what does the female narrator want to say?

My hearing from around 0:13~

> We get to that in a minute. But I do wanna talk about your, integration into the Bulls, Michael Jordan a little bit, coz we saw a clip earlier in the show with that, and, and, look again! From just being even a **young pup covering** you guys, I used to tell people, they're teammates and the brothers out on the court, but it took a lot of work to get there.

My question is,

What is a young pup? [**Merriam Free Online gives the definition as**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pup)

> a young dog

I think the "pup" means Jordan here. Am I correct in understanding her speech or is there alternative slang like meaning?

Saying that, what does "young pup" "covering" mean? Does it mean here Jordan was protecting their teammates also?

I am sorry if there is my mishearing but let me thank you in advance.

Comment: young pups + covering you guys=that's the parse

Comment: @Lambie Thanks. Since I was not able to understand the "pup" means the reporter not Jordan, I was completely changing the sentence(line) to shambles.

Comment: You are so poetic. change to shambles, good one.Unusual.

Comment: @Lambie Haha Unfortunately to you, I'm sorry there is no romance here, since I borrowed the word from a synonym site while I am not sure about the word..:)

Comment: Ok, Kentarosan, here is how it is usually used: The room or house was in shambles. Either completely destroyed or completely disorganized. My life is in shambles. :)

Comment: **A** shambles is an old term for a slaughterhouse. Nowadays we say a place is 'a shambles' if it is extremely untidy and chaotic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “young pup”, meaning young and inexperienced, is the reporter referring to her past self. She “covered”, or reported on, the team.

Comment: Nice! Answer made me to understand her speech 100% clearly.